# get leaks between two points using valgrind

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

i'm using valgrind to find and trace memory issues. Now i want to do something like this:

```
before = getValgrindState();
do_something_curious();
after = getValgrindState();
difference = after - before;
std::cout << difference;
```

Is something like this possible with valgrind?

The MS Visual C++ runtime provides the following functions:

- _CrtMemCheckpoint (to gather the current state of the allocated memory)
- _CrtMemDifference (to calculate the difference between two states)

And i would like to know if there's a way to implement a similar functionality with valgrind.

Comment: My goal is to find the objects which are still present after the function do_something_curious() has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive/destructive way to do what you want is to use `_exit()` (note the underscore) to avoid calling any of the destructors.

- run valgrind/memcheck against your code that calls `_exit()` prior to `do_something_curious();`
- run valgrind/memcheck again with `_exit()` after `do_something_curious();`
- compare results to see what `do_something_curious()` has left around.

[I couldn't figure out how massif would do what you want (is there a way to have massif keep track of `free`/`delete` operations and reconcile with `malloc`/`new` operations that I missed?)]

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It requires a bit more manual work, but it should given me the right result.

Comment: A similar approach, using only one execution, is to call VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK instead of _exit().  See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs You would still have to compare the two reports by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to measure? What is "difference" supposed to be? If you want to examine memory usage, try with valgrind's [massif tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html). [Massif Visualizer](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Massif+Visualizer?content=122409) is useful for interpreting the results.

Comment: the difference object should tell me which objects are allocated and where the memory has gone.